# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face' error even after installing opencv-contrib

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, face-detection, lbph-algorithm

I was trying to implement a face recognition using Python, OpenCv2 and LBPH
(Which is downloaded from [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/SpikeSL/vision-systems.git))

My python version is 2.7.14
PIP version is 9.0.3
and OpenCV version is 3.4.0

and my code is

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import NameFind

# --- import the Haar cascades for face and eye ditection
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haar/haarcascade_frontalcatface.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haar/haarcascade_eye.xml')
spec_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Haar/haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml')

help(cv2.face)
# FACE RECOGNISER OBJECT
LBPH = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create(2, 2, 7, 7, 20)
EIGEN = cv2.face.createEigenFaceRecognizer(10, 5000)
FISHER = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer(5, 500)

# Load the training data from the trainer to recognise the faces
LBPH.load("Recogniser/trainingDataLBPH.xml")
EIGEN.load("Recogniser/trainingDataEigan.xml")
FISHER.load("Recogniser/trainingDataFisher.xml")

# ------------------------------------  PHOTO INPUT  -----------------------------------------------------

img = cv2.imread('Me4.jpg')                  # ------->>> THE ADDRESS TO THE PHOTO

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)                # Convert the Camera to gray
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 4)         # Detect the faces and store the positions
print(faces)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:                                  # Frames  LOCATION X, Y  WIDTH, HEIGHT

    Face = cv2.resize((gray[y: y+h, x: x+w]), (110, 110))   # The Face is isolated and cropped

    ID, conf = LBPH.predict(Face)                           # LBPH RECOGNITION
    print ID
    NAME = NameFind.ID2Name(ID, conf)
    NameFind.DispID(x, y, w, h, NAME, gray)

    ID, conf = EIGEN.predict(Face)                          # EIGEN FACE RECOGNITION
    NAME = NameFind.ID2Name(ID, conf)
    NameFind.DispID3(x, y, w, h, NAME, gray)

    ID, conf = FISHER.predict(Face)                         # FISHER FACE RECOGNITION
    NAME = NameFind.ID2Name(ID, conf)
    NameFind.DispID2(x, y, w, h, NAME, gray)

cv2.imshow('LBPH Face Recognition System', gray)           # IMAGE DISPLAY
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm getting This error when i run any face recognition files like **Recogniser_Image_All_Algorithms.py**

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "Recogniser_Image_All_Algorithms.py", line 11, in 
>       LBPH = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create(2, 2, 7, 7, 20) AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'

I've googled the error and found the same answers like [THIS ONE](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10516)

after checking those feeds i tried to install opencv-contrib using **python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python**

it says

> Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in
>   c:\users\rak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages Requirement already
>   satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in c:\users\rak\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
>   (from opencv-contrib-python)

but the error remains same, how to fix this error. plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have installed opencv for python using **sudo apt install python-opencv**
& received error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'".
My system configuration is OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS & Python 2.7.12. I used following command to resolve the issue:
**sudo apt remove python-opencv**
And installed same library using pip 
**sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python**

Now opencv is working absolutely fine.

Answer (score 5):

I find out the problem myself! The problem was I had **opencv-python** installed, i *uninstalled opencv-python* and ran **pip install opencv-contrib-python** it worked.

Comment: yeah. I searched for this answer. I couldn't find any answer which explains what is happening. everyone says install opencv contrib but it was showing requirement satisfied. so did some digging n find out the prob. tysm

Answer (score 0):

In my Rpi
python version is 3.5 and 2.7 both. opencv version is 3.3.0 
to change python platform from 2.7.x to 3.5.x... 
go to program /python idle/ properties,desktop entry / browse/ select idle-python3.5
in face recognition module has no attribute "face". after changing python platform this problem will be solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
recognizer = cv2.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

try this out