# Image processing with OpenCV- AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

I try to run following "trying.py" but get above error. How to fix it?

**trying.py**

```py
import cv2, os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Create Local Binary Patterns Histograms for face recognization
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

# Using prebuilt frontal face training model, for face detection
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");


# Create method to get the images and label data
def getImagesAndLabels(path):
    # Get all file path
    imagePaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path)]

    # Initialize empty face sample
    faceSamples = []

    # Initialize empty id
    ids = []

    # Loop all the file path
    for imagePath in imagePaths:

        # Get the image and convert it to grayscale
        PIL_img = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')

        # PIL image to numpy array
        img_numpy = np.array(PIL_img, 'uint8')

        # Get the image id
        id = int(os.path.split(imagePath)[-1].split(".")[1])
        print(id)

        # Get the face from the training images
        faces = detector.detectMultiScale(img_numpy)

        # Loop for each face, append to their respective ID
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            # Add the image to face samples
            faceSamples.append(img_numpy[y:y + h, x:x + w])

            # Add the ID to IDs
            ids.append(id)

    # Pass the face array and IDs array
    return faceSamples, ids


# Get the faces and IDs
faces, ids = getImagesAndLabels('dataset')

# Train the model using the faces and IDs
recognizer.train(faces, np.array(ids))

# Save the model into trainer.yml
recognizer.save('trainer/trainer.yml')
```

**Error:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\HP\PycharmProjects\face_identificiation\trying.py", line 12, in 
> recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face' error even after installing opencv-contrib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012528/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-face-error-even-after-install)

Comment: [tour], [ask]. google your error, do the research.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your issue, remember to approve one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you installed the wrong OpenCV version.

Importing `face` will fail (I am using v4.6.0), since the module is not included in the "normal" install of OpenCv.

Try running `pip list` and check for the OpenCv Version. My guess is, that you installed normal OpenCv that will give you an entry like:

`opencv-python                      4.6.0.66`

If that is the case, you should first uninstall opencv-python with `pip uninstall opencv-python` before you install OpenCv with contrib packages, using `pip install opencv-contrib-python`.

Your entry with `pip list` should then contain

`opencv-contrib-python              4.6.0.66`

With that, your code should work!

Edit: I should add, that you overwrote the keyword `id` in your code and you should rename your variable to something else, e.g. `id_doc` or so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade
```

If it didn't work, you can uninstall opencv-contrib-python using this command:

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
```

And install it again.